# Converting datetime from YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss to YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss format

Tags: c#, datetime, format

I have the DateTimeStamp coming from XML input. It looks like this, `"2016-06-13T15:02:41+0800"`.

I need to insert this value to db after converting into `"YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss"` format. How Can I do this in c#?

Comment: You better pass an instance of the DateTime struct to the database then passing a string representing a datetime value.

Comment: by `DateTime.ParseExact` obtain the `DateTime` value, which you can insert into database via *parametrized* query

Answer (score 3):

You can convert the String to DateTime Like this

```
 string date = "2016-06-13T15:02:41+0800";
 DateTime dateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(date);
```

this will return the value as: 13-06-2016 12:32:41

i hope this will solve your problem

Comment: This is the same solution I'm suggesting.

Comment: Thank you very much Ravi Kanth. It helped me.

Comment: @SanthoshkumarLM Are you _really_ sure wanna get _that_ value? Because this way generates completely different value rather than your XML string. Check my answer as well.

Comment: Hi @Ravi,  the above solution worked till yesterday(29th-June). But today It started acting wierdly. i.e. today i got the XML string as 2016-07-01T10:00:00+0800 after converting the expected value was : 2016-07-01 10:00:00 i.e. (July 1st) But, it interpreted differently and returned the value 2016-01-07 10:00:00(July 1st) So my SSIS package did not work as expected. FYI, my destination db is SQL SERVER

Answer (score 1):

You *already* marked your answer (which I think the selected answer is *kind of* wrong) but I *have to* point a few things if you let me..

First of all, using `Convert.ToDateTime` is not a good way in this case. Why?

Because this method returns a `DateTime` instance which `Kind` property is `Local` since your string has time zone information. That means the date and time of this `DateTime` instance is converted to the time in the local time zone. That's why I *strongly* doubt that this is the value you really want.

It converts to `UTC` time first which will be equal to `2016-06-13 07:02:41`. After that, it will adds the local time zone offset to *that* value. In [Ravi Kanth's case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38047474/447156), it looks like `UTC +05:30` for example..

Instead of parsing to `DateTime`, I would suggest you parse it to [`DateTimeOffset`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset) which fits better to your string.

```
var s = "2016-06-13T15:02:41+0800";
var dto = DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(s, "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszzz", 
                                    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Now you have a `DateTimeOffset` as `13.06.2016 15:02:41 +08:00` and you can call it's one of [`UtcDateTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.utcdatetime), [`LocalDateTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.localdatetime) or [`DateTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.datetime) properties whichever you want.

> I need to insert this value to db after converting into "YYYY-MM-DD
> hh:mm:ss" format.

Wait a second.. Which database do you use exactly? Do **not** have a [bad habit to kick as choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type). If you use one of the popular RMDS like Sql Server, Oracle, DB2 etc.. they all have *related* datetime types for that. In such a case, don't insert your `DateTime` values with their string representations, *directly* insert them with preferable via [prepared statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement). If you use a db like SQLite, that's not a case since SQLite saves DateTime values either `TEXT` or `INTEGER` as a [Unix Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).

Comment: Dear Soner, Thanks for the Explanation. 

As u said, the above solution worked till yesterday(29th-June). But today It started acting wierdly. 

i.e. today i got the XML string as 2016-07-01T10:00:00+0800

after converting the expected value was : 2016-07-01 10:00:00
i.e. (July 1st)

But, it interpreted differently and returned the value 2016-01-07 10:00:00(July 1st)

So my SSIS package did not work as expected.

FYI, my destination db is SQL SERVER